# Dart2js numeric types: determining if a value is an int or a double

Tags: dart, dart2js

I'm trying to determine if a `dynamic` parameter to a function is really an `int` or a `double` and I'm finding surprising behavior (at least to me).

Can anyone explain this output (produced on dartpad)?

```
foo(value) {
  print("$value is int: ${value is int}");
  print("$value is double: ${value is double}");
  print("$value runtimetype: ${value.runtimeType}");
}

void main() {
  foo(1);
  foo(2.0);
  int x = 10;
  foo(x);
  double y = 3.1459;
  foo(y);
  double z = 2.0;
  foo(z);
}
```

The output:

```
1 is int: true
1 is double: true
1 runtimetype: int
2 is int: true
2 is double: true
2 runtimetype: int
10 is int: true
10 is double: true
10 runtimetype: int
3.1459 is int: false
3.1459 is double: true
3.1459 runtimetype: double
2 is int: true
2 is double: true
2 runtimetype: int
```

Comment: Seems that the `runtimeType` adapts to the value. `z += 0.1;
  foo(z);` gives `2.1 runtimetype: double`

Comment: Are you running on the VM or via dart2js?

Comment: @SethLadd These results were obtained on dartpad, but we also see weirdness in Chrome (so I think dart2js was involved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the browser there is no distinction possible between `int` and `double`.
JavaScript doesn't provide any such distinction and introducing a custom type for this purpose would have a strong impact on performance, which is why this wasn't done.

Therefore for web applications it's usually better to stick with `num`.

You can check if a value is integer by using for example:

```
var val = 1.0;
print(val is int);
```

prints `true`

**This only indicates that the fraction part is or is not `0`.**

In the browser there is no type information attached to the value, so `is int` and `is double` seem to just check to see if there is a fractional component to the number and decide based on that alone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but your example doesn't seem to work on dartpad. Is dartpad using the VM or a javascript backend?

Comment: Dartpad is using `dart2js` to generate JavaScript. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/29693618d1199b1bc5131a627f09a0e6 Perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Above code is supposed to print `true`. It just checks if the value has a fragment part different from 0.

Comment: When you say there is no distinction between int and double in the browser, then why does `3.1459 is int` produce a different result than `3.1459 is double` on dartpad?

Comment: There is different JS created for `is int` and `is double`. What I meant is that there is no type information attached to the value that allows to distinguish if the value is int or double. It seems `is int` does something similar as I did in the code in my answer. It just checks if the value has a fragment != 0. `0.0 is int` also returns `true`.

Comment: I incorporated your comments into the answer. Please edit if you wish.

Comment: The comment "a value is an integer" and then "1.0 is int == true" is confusing. I'm not actually checking if a value is an integer with the code written. I can, however, check if a value is a num.

Comment: @SethLadd that's the point of the answer. The question is about checking for `int` not checking for `num`. I'll try to make it more clear. Thanks for your effort.