# How to stop Dart demoting doubles to ints

Tags: dart

I want to use doubles in my code but Dart converts them to ints (or dynamic).

I have tried to cast them using 'as' or .toDouble() but they do not stay as doubles:

(in dartpad)

```
main() {
  print ((1.0 as double).runtimeType);
  print (1.0.toDouble().runtimeType);
}
```

(output)

```
int
int
```

I would have expected the output of these statements to be 'double'. If I change the value to 1.1 I get a double out.

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954219/8745788 this happens only in dart2js, eg. running the dart sdk with this code works as expected